# How can I read file over command line in JAVA?

Tags: java, readfile

Is that possible to read file over command line like this.

```
java Main config.txt
```

Main class is,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
```

It returns "config.txt". I want to send file through command line. Is this doable?

Comment: What do you mean send the file to the command line? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java

Comment: @Daniel Thank you very much. It is what I need :)